Zod on new Typescript project errors with "Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher"
I've created a new Typescript project using
mkdir zod-ts
cd zod-ts
npm init // all options default
npx tsc init

This creates the following tsconfig.json
target: es2016
module: commonjs
strict: true
esModuleInterop: true
skipLibCheck: true
forceConsistentCasingInFileNames: true

I install zod and other packages with npm install zod @types/node typescript
I then create an index.ts file with the following code
import { z } from "zod";
const myType = z.object({
    myprop: z.string().optional(),
});

console.log(myType);

I then run tsc index.ts and I'm greeted with the following error: node_modules/zod/lib/types.d.ts:777:5 - error TS18028: Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher.
As skipLibCheck: true I'd expect it to ignore this, but it's not.
What am I doing wrong here?

ANSWER
tsc was not the right command to run.
It should be npx ts-node index.ts (install the ts-node package) first.
